# Is there any problem (EMC/EMI) with routing in parallel on several layer for better performance?

Tags: power, pcb-design, emc, high-current, routing

[image]I have a high-current 220-volt AC power trace on my PCB. for this inrush power of want to use this trace parallel to each other.

1. I want to know this way have positive effect?
2. Do this parallel trace reduce to resistance?
3. Does the inrush current situation get better?

[image: both trace have one net]

Is there any problem with using parallel traces in several layers to strengthen the power signal? They are relay contacts.

Comment: What currents are you expecting and why do you think you need multiple traces for the same signal?

Comment: 220V AC has no EMC implications. What are you doing with it? That's the real question. What components are pictured here?

Comment: for this inrush power of want to use this trace parallel to each other. 
I want to know this way have positive effect?
do this parallel trace reduce to resistance?
Does the inrush current situation get better?

Comment: Title asks about EMI. Body asks about inrush. Please clarify.

Comment: Both of them. but now i find out i don't have EMC issue so inrush current is much important to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "strengthen the power" I assume you mean that you want to reduce losses/heating. Running parallel traces on other layers is a common method to achieve that. You should have no EMC/EMI trouble because of this as long as you are not routing signal traces between the high current traces on additional layers or cutting up a ground plane or something which it doesn't look like you are doing. As always, keep an eye on your spacings with high voltage.

Edit to answer specifics added to questions: This will be good/have a positive effect on inrush current handling capability. The parallel traces will reduce resistance so it can handle inrush current better. Actual inrush current might actually go up a negligible amount because of the reduced resistance but the other parts of the circuit that determine inrush current will have a much larger impact so don't worry about this. Inrush current handling will get better. Actual inrush current will effectively stay the same. If you want to reduce inrush current you will need to do that another way.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer Red Dragon. can you please tell me some way that helps me to control and reduce this inrush current?

Comment: It really depends on the system and circuit details what would be an appropriate inrush current reduction technique. First I would make sure you really need it though and that just doing your parallel traces isn't good enough. You don't want to be adding components you don't actually need. But if it is really needed generally you would want to lower voltage, increase resistance, or control timing (apply voltage more slowly). Some internet research will probably serve you well for what is best for your system. Try https://www.ametherm.com/ and TI app note slva670a to get started.